# How to store objects in DynamoDB list attribute

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble storing an array of objects in DynamoDB.

I'm storing a game leaderboard in a table for various maps and game types, and I have a list as an attribute of each element. Each "leaderboard" is put into the table like so:

```
Item: {
    'map': { S: mapName },
    'type': { S: type },
    'times': { L: [] }
}
```

I'm trying to add objects to this times array, so that the times array stores names and times, for something hopefully like so:

```
{
    ...
    times: [
        { name: 'aaa', time: 12.345 },
        { name: 'bbb', time: 23.456 },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

So I'm running the following update expression, but the problem is that it only adds the name and the time field is ignored silently:

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'leaderboard',
    Key: {
        'map': { S: map },
        'type': { S: type },
    },
    UpdateExpression: `SET #listAttr = list_append(#listAttr, :itemValue)`,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#listAttr": 'times',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":itemValue": { L: [{ S: name, N: time }] },
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
};

const command = new UpdateItemCommand(params);

client.send(command)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error updating item: ' + err);
    })
```

The query succeeds, but after running the query, the element looks as follows, with no sign of the time as specified for the :itemValue in the ExpressionAttributeValues:

```
{
    ...
    times: [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ],
    ...
}
```

What gives? Thanks!

Comment: I would highly suggest you use `DocumentClient` utility because it abstracts the whole data type problem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-dynamodb-utilities.html